# Change legend title in ggplot with both shape and color

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm trying to change the title of my legend, but I only know how to rename it using `col` or `shape`, which gives me an extra legend - one based on the `shape` and one based on `col`.
Does anyone know how to fix it so that I get one legend with a custom made title that shows the symbol both with their `shape` and `col`?

Here's my graph:

```
mtcars
Library(ggplot2 )
library(ggpmisc)

formula <- y~x

ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, drat, col=factor(cyl), shape=factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",formula = formula) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#000000", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9")) +
  theme_bw() +
  stat_poly_eq(
    aes(label = paste(stat(adj.rr.label), stat(p.value.label), sep = "*\", \"*")),
    formula = formula, parse = TRUE, size=3)
```

Comment: Not sure whether I got you right. If you want one legend for both color and shape with a custom title you can do it via `labs(color = "Legend title", shape = "Legend Title")`, i.e. give "both" legends the same name.

Comment: Yes exactly thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stefan: Not sure whether I got you right. If you want one legend for both color and shape with a custom title you can do it via labs(color = "Legend title", shape = "Legend Title"), i.e. give "both" legends the same name.